# how to get different colors in barplot in R

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am trying to get a simple bar plot where my data has both positive and negative numbers. Want to make the colours different for positive and negative bars.

```
data <- c(-0.52, 0.25,  0.07, -0.44,  0.04, -0.16, -0.45, -1.44, -0.12, -0.17, -0.54, -0.04, -0.47, -0.40,  0.03, -0.78, -0.35 -0.52,  0.25, -0.69,  0.08, 1.11)
barplot(data, col=c("blue","black"))
```

I tried using a vector for the color

```
barplot(data,col=c("blue", "blue", "black", "blue", "black", "blue", "blue", "blue", 
                     "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "black", "blue", 
                     "blue", "blue", "black", "blue", "black", "blue"))
```

But it takes only the first color. Is it possible to get it in base graphics without ggplot? Thanks for any reply

Comment: `barplot(data, col=ifelse(data <= 0, "blue","black") )`

Comment: sorry missed that post. will be more careful next time. that post is brilliant and thanks @thelatemail or pointing me to that post.